# Concat subscriptions in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, concatenation, subscription

I need to subscribe to two different things in the ngOnInit of a given component:

1. To a get request included in an Angular service already created, from which I will fetch a list of items (*sourceOptions* in the code).
2. To the route.queryParams of my url, so I can use one of these params to call a function which will also use the list of items fetched in point 1.

The issue here is that I need somehow to concat them in a given order (1. then 2.) because the function called in 2 *setSelected(params["sourceTool"*] is using the list of items mentioned.

Could it be done with rxjs concat operator? How should it be coded?

Thanks

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.searchApi.getSourceTools()
      .subscribe(response => {
        response.items.forEach((sourceTool: string) => {
          this.sourceOptions.push({
            description: sourceTool,
            selected: false
          })
        })
      })

  this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
       this.setSelected(params["sourceTool"])
    })

}
```

Comment: You can use concatMap in this case.

Comment: Which would be the difference between concatMap and the switchMap option provided in the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  this.searchApi.getSourceTools()
    .pipe(
      tap(response => {
        response.items.forEach((sourceTool: string) => {
          this.sourceOptions.push({
            description: sourceTool,
            selected: false
          })
        })
      }), 
      switchMap(() => this.route.queryParams)
     )
     .subscribe(params => {
       this.setSelected(params["sourceTool"])
    });
```

If I understand correctly your problem, you can easily use `switchMap` operator to change the source observable after initial source emit value (with side effects execution)

Comment: Thanks it works as expected. I am not really familiar with rxjs yet. BR